# use nextgen gallery functions in a plugin

Tags: php, include, xml-parsing, preloading, nextgen-gallery

I am trying to write a simple Wordpress plugin to read an XML feed and put the data into a custom post.
The data is from a property website.
I can read all the information in and use `wp_insert_post( $mypost, $wp_error );` to create the new post and I can set the terms and update the meta for this post, but I am stumped when trying to get the images into Nextgen gallery.

I can read all the urls for the images. What I would like to do, is create a new gallery for a property, then add the images to this gallery.

I have tried `nggAdmin::create_gallery($title, $defaultpath);`
and also

```
$result = $wpdb->query("
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->nggallery (name, slug, path, title, galdesc, pageid, previewpic, author)
    VALUES (‘testgallery’, ‘testgallery’, ‘wp-content/gallery/testgallery’, ‘testgallery’, ”, 0, 0, 1)";
```

I just get a blank screen.

Can someone tell me what INCLUDES to put  in the file and how to call the functions needed from Nextgen gallery.

Comment: Hope you aren't using fancy quotes `’` in your real code

Comment: woops, no I put this - $result = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $wpdb->nggallery (name, slug, title, author) VALUES ( "wpwtest3","wpwtest3","WPWtest3","1");